# React axios post binary data to Strapi

Tags: javascript, curl, axios, fetch, strapi

I currently struggle with the fact that this line here works:

```
curl -X POST -F 'files=@/data/path/to/image.png' http://192.168.168.50:1337/upload
```

And neither `fetch` nor `axios` work with the following requests:

```js
    // Approach with fetch.
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      // formData.append("file", new Blob([reader.result]), file.name);  // Found both online
      formData.append("file", new Blob([reader.result]));  // Tested both with same behavior.

      const url = "http://192.168.168.50:1337/upload";
      fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", //boundary=${formData._boundary}`,
        },
        body: formData,
      }).then(res=>console.log(res));
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

```js
    // Approach with axios.
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      // formData.append("file", new Blob([reader.result]), file.name);  // Found both online
      formData.append("file", new Blob([reader.result]));  // Tested both with same behavior.

      const url = "http://192.168.168.50:1337/upload";
      axios.post(url, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data;`, // boundary=${dat._boundary}`,
        },
        data: formData,
        }
      ).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Is there something obvious that i overlook?

Thanks!